# Como fazer update do Apache2 no Dedian 9 (Stretch)?

Tags: apache, linux

Estou usando a versão 2.4.10 do Apache, no Debian 9. No entanto, essa versão do Apache, que eu estou usando, é do Debian 8.

Gostaria de saber como faço para atualizar o Apache2 para a [**versão 2.4.25**](https://packages.debian.org/source/stretch/apache2).

Comment: não existe versão 2.10.10 do apache, na verdade 2.10 seria maior que 2.4, então, mas não lançado nenhuma versão acima do 2.4 ainda. Você deve estar fazendo alguma confusão.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta.

Comment: Como esta o seu source.list?

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida A resposta respondeu a sua pergunta?

Comment: @gfleck Desculpa não ter respondido. Sim, respondeu. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digite no seu terminal como **ROOT**:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
```

Ou se quiser atualizar somente o apache veja os pacotes que precisam ser atualizados no seu sistema com o comando `apt list --upgradable` e depois instale somente os pacotes relacionados ao apache, exemplo:

```
apt install apache2-bin/stable
```